# dynamic_cast<A*>(this) in method of class B?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I have a quite special situation in my C++ program.

Look at the following class setup:

```
class Base1 {
  public: void baseMethod();
}

class Base2 : public Base1 {
  ...
}

class Common {
  public: void commonMethod();
}

class Derived1 : public Base1, public Common {
  ...
}

class Derived2 : public Base2, public Common {
  ...
}
```

`Base1` and `Base2` are unchangeable for me as they are part of a library.

What I want to achieve is that both `Derived1` and `Derived2` share the same method `commonMethod()`, so I use class `Common` with that method as a common base for `Derived1` and `Derived2`.

The problem now is that `commonMethod()` shall contain a call to `baseMethod()` which is defined in `Base1`! In the context of a `Derived1`- or `Derived2`-object this is legal, but how to define that method in `Common`?

I know that if I would declare `Base2` as virtual derived class from `Base1` and the same for `Common`, it shouldn't be a problem (at least for `Derived2`, not sure about `Derived1`). But as I can't modify `Base2` that's not possible anyway.

Also letting `Common` inherit from `Base2` and then `Derived1` and `Derived2` solely from `Common` doesn't work because I don't want `Derived1` to inherit from `Base2`!

What then came to my mind was to make a dynamic_cast within `commonMethod()`:

```
void Common::commonMethod() {
  ...
  Base1* self = dynamic_cast<Base1*>(this);
  if(self) {
    self->baseMethod();
  }
  ...
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is a "nice" solution...

Do you have any ideas how to make it better? Or do you think this solution isn't bad at all? :)

Comment: commonMethod need Base1 object while Derived2 has nothing to do with Base1, so Common has nothing to do with Derived2. You need first create connection between Base1 and Derived2, otherwise Common is meaningless for Derived2

Comment: @JackyZhu: I'm sorry, I don't get your point exactly. Derived2 inherits from Base2 which inherits from Base1, so Derived2 inherits indirectly from Base1, too.

Comment: Base on Eric Z post, the common seams only an util class, what's the reason you need Derived1 and Derived2 inheriate from it. inheritate it doesn't have any benifit. Inheritate should not be used as an approach for reuse code. Why not just rename common as util and you can use it as you want?

Comment: @ZijingWu: Maybe I've used a bit too vague class names in the code above. In my real case Common (it isn't called Common there btw) in fact defines a behaviour that both derived classes have in common and that should be visible and accessable from outside. So in MY case the inheritance approach is really the more suitable solution.

Comment: @C_S Sorry, I missed this part. Then composite rather than inheritance should be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only purpose of `Common` is to provide a *common* implementation of that one method, you can use the CRTP pattern and template it on the type of the base. At this point you could decide whether it makes sense to keep it as multiple bases of the `DerivedX` types or it could make sense to linearize the inheritance hierarchy:

```
// Option1
template <typename Derived>
struct Common {
   void commonFunction() { ... static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo(); ... }
};
struct Derived1 : Base1, Common<Derived1>

// Option2 (not strictly CRTP, but close)
template <typename Base>
struct Common : Base {
   void commonFunction() { ... this->foo(); ... } // keep the this-> here
};
struct Derived1 : Common<Base1>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd choose ***composition*** over ***multiple inheritance***, i.e. to define `common` as a member object of derived classes.

```
class Base1 {
  public: void baseMethod();
}

class Base2 : public Base1 {}

class Common {
  public: 
     Common(Base1 *base): m_base(base) {}
     void Common::commonMethod()
     {
        m_base->baseMethod();
     }
  private:
     Base1 *m_base;
}

class Derived1 : public Base1
{
  public:
     Derived2(): m_common(this) {}
  private:
     Common m_common;
}

class Derived2 : public Base2
{
  public:
     Derived2(): m_common(this) {}
  private:
     Common m_common;
}
```

There is a potential risk of going this way though. Since member object(`Common`) is constructed first before the outer object(`Derived1` or `Derived2`), you want to make sure no methods from the `Derivedx` object is called in `Common`'s constructor.

Comment: Nice solution, too! It would work, but I decided to use the CRTP pattern as the composition approach would also make need of delegate methods or at least getters for the Common interface.

Comment: +1 because the inheritate should not be used as an approach for reuse code. inheritate means "is-a".